# Giving my personal info because of Anti-Spam

Tags: spam, legal, mailchimp, address

I have just signed up for MailChimp because I want to send emails to my subscribers from my website.
There is an Anti-Spam law with these rules:

- You must include your contact information inside every promotional campaign that you send, including a physical mailing address or PO Box where you can receive mail. (Not a website or email address.)
- You may not falsify your contact information or subject line.
- and more
  Here is the [link](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business)

I don't want to send my personal information with every email I send. Is there a way to not send my information and not breaking rules of that law?

Comment: Get a P.O. Box. Easy peasy.

Comment: Is there any other way than P.O.Box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real way to get around these laws. The purpose of these laws is so that there is a physical address at which you can have snail mail sent if someone chooses to send a letter saying they want to be removed from your mailing list. Other than getting a PO Box or providing your personal address the only other way to do this is to work with a legal firm or a mail clearing house company (such as a virtual office company) that provides you with a physical postal address and can relay any deliveries to that address to you electronically.